# How do I handle "Receive" calls being made out of order?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have a WF4 service that emulates a sales funnel.  It works by starting with a "Registration" receive call.  After that, there are 10 similar stages (comprised of a 2 receives at each stage).  You can't advance past a stage until after the current stage validates the data received.  What I'm unsure about though is, even though my client app wouldn't allow for it, how can I make my workflow prevent anyone from calling the receive operations out of order?  In my test console app, I let the user call any receive operation (just because I wanted to see what happens).

For example, if I call the Register first and then the "AddQualification" receive before the "AddProspect" receive, the test app returns with an exception like this:

> Operation 'AddQualification|{http://tempuri.org/}IZSalesFunnelService' on service instance with identifier '1984c927-402b-4fbb-acd4-edfe4f0d8fa4' cannot be performed at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery guarantees

2 things come from this that I don't know how to do:

First, how do I handle the Fault Exception to notify the client in a meaningful way and...

Second, because I'm using persistence (and property promotion), when I make the out of order call, the properties that are promoted unload.  They are not promoted again after the client gets the exception.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question I'd look at Rory Primroses post on how to shield Content Correlation Failures: [Managing Content Correlation Failures](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/11/09/Managing-content-correlation-failures.aspx). In here he translates an exception into a valid Business Exception.

Comment: That link hasn't worked since you've sent it...any other source for the same info?

Comment: Yeah I see. Okay, so basically what you want to do is implement  [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599828.aspx) somewhere, and in that check for the exception being thrown. Then check the FaultException's and it's namespace code for "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2008/10/WorkflowServices". Might want to check [Ron Jacob's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/01/15/wcf-4-tenets-of-service-oriented-data-validation.aspx) too.

Comment: Original link seems to be up again: [Managing Content Correlation Failures](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/11/09/Managing-content-correlation-failures.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, my server is playing up a little so the blog keeps going off the air temporarily.

With regard to your second question, you need to make sure that your workflow service is set to Abandon for unhandled exceptions. Here is the doco for AppFabric for this setting:

---

Abandon. The service host aborts the workflow service instance in memory. The state of the instance in the database remains “Active”. The Workflow Management Service recovers the abandoned workflow instance from last persistence point saved in the persistence database.

Abandon and suspend. The service host aborts the workflow service instance in memory and sets the state of the instance in the persistence database to “Suspended”. A suspended instance can be resumed or terminated later by using IIS Manager. These instances are not recovered by the Workflow Management Service automatically.

Terminate. The service host aborts the workflow service instance in memory, and sets the state of the instance in the persistence database to “Completed (Terminated)”. A terminated instance cannot be resumed later.

Cancel. The service host cancels the workflow service instance causing all the cancellation handlers to be invoked so that a workflow terminates in a graceful manner, and sets the state of the instance in the persistence database to “Completed (Cancelled)”.

---

Abandon is the only setting that will hold onto your workflow in the persistence store so that you can then call it again.

Hope this helps.