# WCF Workflow Service breaking workflow yields timeout

Tags: wcf, web-services, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have a WCF Workflow Service (running on AppFabric) that accepts a `Connect` receive operation, and then move on to listen to a number of other operations.

When trying to break the workflow from my unit test, by invoking `Connect` twice, the service won't respond on my second request, but will wait until a timeout occurs.

I am expecting an error message such as this one:

[How do I handle "Receive" calls being made out of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121229/how-do-i-handle-receive-calls-being-made-out-of-order)

> Operation 'AddQualification|{http://tempuri.org/}IZSalesFunnelService' on service instance with identifier '1984c927-402b-4fbb-acd4-edfe4f0d8fa4' cannot be performed at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery guarantees

**Note**
The behaviour looks like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541703/workflow-services-receiveandsendreply-unordered-calls-timeout), but the current workflow does not use any delays.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are still being bitten by the same issue as in the other question you are referring to. This is a bug in the workflow runtime scheduler.